# How to specify an ELSE condition with WHEN?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex

Given this code (pseudo)

```
MERGE INTO ...
    (SELECT ... FROM ...) ...
ON (...)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (...) VALUES (...);

    //This is Oracle Apex code
    apex_application.g_unrecoverable_error := true;
    htp.init();
    owa_util.redirect_url('f?p=111:11:&APP_SESSION.::NO:::');
```

How would add a condition so that when it doesn't match it, I need to run this line of code:

```
apex_application.g_notification := 'My error';
```

I am not sure what to do to make it work. I tried some ELSE and additional WHEN statements but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware you will not be able to extend the MERGE statement in this way. You can take a count of of table being inserted into before and after to determine whether any rows fell into the NOT MATCHED section and got inserted.

Put your logic in an IF statement using that count.

Answer (score 0):

In a `MERGE` statement depending on the `ON cond`

- you issue a `UPDATE` and optionally `DELETE` if `MATCHED`
- you issue a `INSERT` if `NOT MATRCHED`

Your apex code can not be part of the `MERGE` statement. You have to figure out a different strategy for it.

Comment: Well..what I have in the question works...basically I redirect to a different page whenever that procedure runs. So it is not conditional right now, but i would like it to be. I want to redirect when it is NOT matched. And display error when it is MATCHED.

Comment: Your code runs, out side the `merge` statement, independent of the outcome of the `merge` statement.